# Position a p element in footer

Tags: css, css-position

I can't position the `<p>` vertically in the footer. I have tried to give `p` the values:
`vertical-align:middle;` and `margin-bottom:10px;` but it is not working.

Link to the code: http://jsfiddle.net/CL55P/

HTML:

```
<footer>
        <p id="sidfot">Kontakta oss på:
        <a href="mailto:info@snickrat.se">info@snickrat.se</a> eller 073 - 729 87 97</p>        
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer{
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-box-shadow:    2px 3px 6px -0.5px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px -0.5px #ccc;
    box-shadow:         0px -3px 6px -0.5px #ccc;
    background-color:#BFBDBF;}
    #sidfot{text-align:center;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/. Skip down to the `So how do I vertically-center something?!` part. Or maybe http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `line-height: 40px` of the parent footer element is overriding the line-height of the p, which inherits that value, and pushing it to the bottom of the element.

setting line-height should help:

```
footer p {
    line-height: 14px;
}
```

Comment: This is not quite right. Is a browser default margin witch was pushing the <p> down.

Answer (score 1):

You can try giving the p span these properties:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle
```

Comment: I tested your solution, jsfiddled here : http://jsfiddle.net/CL55P/5/.
You should add to your answer that the <p> tag now needs to be 100% width and set with height because table-cell are collapsed by default. -1 for the one who +1 your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin: 0;` and `line-height: 40px;` to `#sidfot` like so:

```
#sidfot {
    margin: 0;
    line-height:40px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Here's the updated jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/CL55P/2/

Comment: Line height is not necessary since it's inherited from <footer>

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make `<footer>` 40px high,

```
footer {
    clear:both; /* this is useless since width is 100% */
    width:100%; /* while you position in fixed, you should use left:Xpx; right:Xpx; instead */
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px; /* 0 (zero) do not need a mesurement unit. remove px  */
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px -0.5px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px -0.5px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0px -3px 6px -0.5px #ccc;
    background-color:#BFBDBF;
}
#sidfot {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:14px;
    vertical-align:middle; /* this will position text in middle of line-height */
    line-height:40px; /* this will force footer height */
    margin:0; /* make sure this is reset, otherwise, browser default margin will apply */
}
```

And you can remove line-height from `<footer>`

[Your jsFiddle updated here](http://jsfiddle.net/CL55P/4/)